# How To Disable Bell/Ding/Bing/Sound in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm using the mongo shell to try some stuff out on MongoDB, but that bell (ding, bind, sound, etc) keeps irritating me.  I know how to disable it in bash and vim, but I can't find a way to disable it in the mongo shell.  I can't find the answer from Googling.  Maybe I'm using the wrong words.  Does anyone know how to disable it?